# New favicon doesn't scale down to 16x16

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, favicon

I noticed the change of the favicon and saw it confirmed in this question:

> [Why did the Stack Overflow icon (favicon) change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228294/179259)

Seeing the old/new designs, I feel a bit uneasy, but I acknowledge that this might be the fear of change inside all of us. However, I do have concerns regarding the smaller version; it really feels like trying to cram too many bars together, whether the old version just reduced the number of bars so they looked *nicer*. A comparison:

32x32: old [image: Old 32px], new [image: new 32px]

16x16: old [image: Old 16px], new [image: new 16px]

**Do you agree that the new, smaller version looks too tiny and a mechanism similar to the old one would be better?**

<sub>Meta-meta question: should I ask this question at [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)?</sub>

Comment: **+1** [This is exactly what I meant, but didn't have the words for.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228294/why-did-the-stack-overflow-icon-favicon-change#comment748322_228296)

Comment: Oh, I thought that you meant that both of them, including the boxes, looked thinner.

Comment: Agreed, it's even worse on the Chrome browser tab than on the white background in the question here.

Comment: I'm not native, what does "Not to dis you here Jin" mean? Sorry for not understanding, but it seems there's no one named Jin here S:

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia [Jin's our chief designer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin), and the responsible entity `^W^W` culprit here.

Comment: Thanks, now your comment makes sense to me (: